# Is std::function as efficient as using auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Say I have a lambda I want to define. I can do it like this,

```
auto foo = [] (int x)
{
  return x == 42;
};
```

or this,

```
std::function<bool(int)> foo = [] (int x)
{
  return x == 42;
};
```

Is there any penalty for doing the second one? Does `std::function` have overhead I should be wary of? I don't use it very often; only when doing recursion.

Comment: Yes, type erasure has costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) does incur a cost for a good discussion of this cost you can read [Efficient Use of Lambda Expressions and std::function](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059).